# How can i get the First Date and Last Date between selected months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

How can i get the First Date and Last Date between selected months?

For example I Enter year 2015, and month 09  to 2016 08

The return values must be:

```
StartDate EndDate   
20150901 20150930  
20151001 20151031  
20151101 20151130  
20151201 20151231  
20160101 20160131  
20160201 20160229  
20160301 20160331   
20160401 20160430      
20160501 20160531   
20160601 20160630   
20160701 20160731   
20160801 20160831
```

I've found multiple queries that do the same but just for 1 inserted date. for example:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101) AS Date_Value,
'First Day of Current Month' AS Date_Type
UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),101) ,
'Last Day of Current Month'
```

But I couldn't find one that can do this for Between statement

Comment: Found it :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195750/how-to-get-current-month-name-start-date-and-end-date-between-two-dates-in-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I have two udf's which can be used independently or in conjunction.  They dynamically create date ranges with variable dateparts and/or increments.

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2015-09-01','2016-08-01','MM',1) 

DateR1                  DateR2
2015-09-01 00:00:00.000 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000
2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 2015-11-01 00:00:00.000
2015-11-01 00:00:00.000 2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-01 00:00:00.000 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000
2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

Now, I specifically use the cap so I can query data (including time) which are between the DateR1 and DateR2 and

However, with a little twist, you can change the output.  For example:

```
Select DateR1=cast(DateR1 as Date),DateR2=DateAdd(DD,-1,cast(DateR2 as Date)) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2015-09-01','2016-08-01','MM',1) 

DateR1      DateR2
2015-09-01  2015-09-30
2015-10-01  2015-10-31
2015-11-01  2015-11-30
2015-12-01  2015-12-31
2016-01-01  2016-01-31
2016-02-01  2016-02-29
2016-03-01  2016-03-31
2016-04-01  2016-04-30
2016-05-01  2016-05-31
2016-06-01  2016-06-30
2016-07-01  2016-07-31
```

The two function are as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End
```

AND

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span] (@Date1 datetime,@Date2 datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2016-01-01','2016-12-31','MM',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date-Span]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1) 

Returns Table 

As
Return (

     Select DateR1 = RetVal
           ,DateR2 = LEAD(RetVal,1,@Date2) OVER (ORDER BY RetVal)
     From (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date](@Date1,@Date2,@DatePart,@Incr) ) A
     Where RetVal<@Date2

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `UDF`s for this - You can do this with a single query:

```
Declare @FromYear   Int = 2015,
        @FromMonth  Int = 9,
        @ToYear     Int = 2016,
        @ToMonth    Int = 8

Declare @FromDate   Date = (Select DateAdd(Year, @FromYear - 1900, DateAdd(Month,  @FromMonth - 1, 0))),
        @ToDate     Date = (Select DateAdd(Year, @ToYear - 1900, DateAdd(Month, @ToMonth - 1, 0)))

;With Date (Date) As
(
    Select  @FromDate Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Month, 1, Date)
    From    Date
    Where   Date < @ToDate
)
Select  Convert(Varchar, Year(Date)) + Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, Month(Date)), 2) + Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, Day(Date)), 2)    As StartDate,
        Convert(Varchar, Year(Date)) + Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, Month(Date)), 2) + Right('00' + Convert(Varchar, Day(DateAdd(Day, -1, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, Date) + 1, 0)))), 2)   As EndDate 
From    Date
Option  (MaxRecursion 0)
```

> Output

```
StartDate   EndDate
20150901    20150930
20151001    20151031
20151101    20151130
20151201    20151231
20160101    20160131
20160201    20160229
20160301    20160331
20160401    20160430
20160501    20160531
20160601    20160630
20160701    20160731
20160801    20160831
```

If you're able to move to SQL Server 2012 or later, however, the query is much simpler:

```
Declare @FromYear   Int = 2015,
        @FromMonth  Int = 9,
        @ToYear     Int = 2016,
        @ToMonth    Int = 8

Declare @FromDate   Date    = DateFromParts(@FromYear, @FromMonth, 1),
        @ToDate     Date    = DateFromParts(@ToYear, @ToMonth, 1)

;With Date (Date) As
(
    Select  @FromDate Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Month, 1, Date)
    From    Date
    Where   Date < @ToDate
)
Select  Format(Date, N'yyyyMMdd')           As StartDate, 
        Format(EoMonth(Date), N'yyyyMMdd')  As EndDate
From    Date
Option  (MaxRecursion 0)
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  The UDF's are very flexible and can be called from numerous queries.   In-short, they server multiple masters.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Nothing against UDFs, they're very practical.  I'm simply saying you don't *need* to have them (as in, they aren't required for it).  And sometimes it's better to have everything self-contained.  Though, that's largely situational and a bit of personal preference :)

Comment: Agreed, sometimes it is better to have every self contained.  That said, I'm a lazy man.  I'd rather do something once and not have to think about it ever again.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Its also a very small script.  I like the idea of the CTE from Siyual.  But this is much shorter.

```
DECLARE @inputYear INT = 2015,
@inputMonth INT = 09

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, @inputMonth-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @inputYear-1900, 0)) AS FirstDayOfTheMonth,
DATEADD(s,-1, DATEADD(MONTH, @inputMonth, DATEADD(YEAR, @inputYear-1900, 0))) AS LastDayOfTheMonth
```

Answer (score -1):

Your task is also possible using one single ANSI sql statement.
However, you need two tables ALL_YEARS and ALL_MONTHS that contain the used set of years and month.

E.g. if you consider possible years between 1900 and 2099, the table ALL_YEARS must contain the numbers between 1900 and 2099.
The table ALL_MONTHS must contain the numbers between 1 and 12.

Using these two tables, the statement looks as follows:

```
select            to_date('01.' || to_char(all_months.month_value) || '.' || to_char(all_years.year_value ), 'dd.mm.yyyy') first_day ,
       add_months(to_date('01.' || to_char(all_months.month_value) || '.' || to_char(all_years.year_value ), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1) -1 last_day
from   all_years,
       all_months
where  to_date('01.' || to_char(all_months.month_value) || '.' || to_char(all_years.year_value ), 'dd.mm.yyyy') between 
        to_date('01.02.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and 
        to_date('01.07.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

The output is as follows:

```
01.02.14    28.02.14
01.03.14    31.03.14
01.04.14    30.04.14
01.05.14    31.05.14
01.06.14    30.06.14
...
01.06.16    30.06.16
01.07.16    31.07.16
```